# React redirect after login (Dispatch)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mern

How can I redirect my website to the homepage once logged in successfully on this kind of projects:

https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern_shopping_list

The action ts file [actions/authActions.ts]:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { returnErrors } from './errorActions';
import {
  USER_LOADED,
  USER_LOADING,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL
} from './types';
import { IAuthFunction, IConfigHeaders } from '../../types/interfaces';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

//

// Register User
export const register = ({ name, email, password }: IAuthFunction) => (
  dispatch: Function
) => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  // Request body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

  axios
    .post('/api/auth/register', body, config)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'REGISTER_FAIL')
      );
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    });
};

// Login User
export const login = ({ email, password }: IAuthFunction) => (
  dispatch: Function
) => { 
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  // Request body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  const history = useHistory();// <---------- ERROR HERE

  axios
    .post('/api/auth/login', body, config)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data
        });
        // const history = useHistory(); <----- tried placing it here too
        // history.push("/dd");
      }
    )
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(
        console.log(err)
        // returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL')
      );
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL
      });
    });
};
```

The catch error returns "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component..."

Comment: Remove any attempt of redirection from your dispatch code. A successful login will ultimately change some component's state (regardless of how), and that's what you use to redirect, either in `useEffect()` if it's a functional component, or `componentDidUpdate()` if it's class based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UseEffect()` like so:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
//
const LoginForm = ({
    isAuthenticated,
    redirectTo, // <-- here
    error,
    login,
    clearErrors
}: ILoginForm) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    //
    useEffect(() => {
      if(redirectTo)
        history.push(redirectTo);
    });
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IAuthReduxProps) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    redirectTo: state.auth.redirectTo, // <-- here
    error: state.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login, clearErrors })(LoginForm);
```

interface.ts:

```
export interface IAuthReduxProps {
  auth: { isAuthenticated: boolean, redirectTo: string }; // <-- here added redirectTo
  error: IError;
}
```

authReducer.ts:

```
case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
  localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
  return {
    ...state,
    ...action.payload,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    isLoading: false,
    redirectTo: "/dd" // <-- here
  };
```